# What happens when awaiting a call on a different thread

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Let's say I invoke a Task like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    await SomeAction();
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

and inside `SomeAction` there's a line like this:

```
await OtherAction();
```

with a regular `await`, the code goes back to the invoking context, but here it's a task running on a different thread. So what happens with the context of the await there? Is it actually like blocking in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> with a regular await, the code goes back to the invoking context, but here it's a task running on a different thread. So what happens with the context of the await there? Is it actually like blocking in this case?

[Here's how `await` works](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). `await` never blocks.

`await` will first examine its awaitable (usually a task); if the awaitable is already complete, then `await` will extract the result (or exception) and just continue executing the method (synchronously). If the awaitable is *not* already complete, *then* `await` will behave asynchronously.

When `await` behaves asynchronously, it will (by default) capture the current "context" (`SynchronizationContext.Current` or, if that is `null`, then `TaskScheduler.Current`), and then return an incomplete task. Since the example code is using `Task.Factory.StartNew` without specifying a `TaskScheduler` (which IMO is always a bug), then its delegate was executed on whatever `TaskScheduler.Current` was at the point `StartNew` was called. So the context that will be captured by the `await` is that same `TaskScheduler.Current`.

**If** `TaskScheduler.Current` was the same as `TaskScheduler.Default` (which is likely but by no means guaranteed), then when the `async` method returns, the thread is returned to the thread pool, and [since `StartNew` doesn't understand `async` lambdas](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), the `Task` returned from `StartNew` is completed. This means the `LongRunning` flag in there just makes things slower; it's the opposite of optimization.

Later, when the `await` completes, it will resume executing the lambda on the captured context (`TaskScheduler.Current`). **If** `TaskScheduler.Current` was the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`, then the lambda will resume executing on a thread newly acquired from the thread pool (possibly the same thread but likely a different one).

---

This sounds crazy complicated, but really that's only because the code is using `StartNew`. If you look at the code using `Task.Run`, it's much simpler because the context is *always* `TaskScheduler.Default` (the thread pool context):

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await SomeAction();
});
```

Now you can say with certainty that if the `await` acts asynchronously, then it will return a task, returning the thread to the thread pool. When `SomeAction` completes, then the lambda will continue executing on a thread pool thread. Also, since `Task.Run` understands `async` lambdas, the task returned from `Task.Run` will not complete until the lambda is complete.

Here's some guidelines:

- [NEVER, EVER, EVER use `Task.Factory.StartNew` without passing a `TaskScheduler`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). This is a 100%-of-the-time, always-on rule.
- For asynchronous code, use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Is it possible if you could elaborate more on what exactly are SynchronizationContext.Current, TaskScheduler.Current, TaskScheduler.Default and the differences between them?

Comment: Also, regarding the last part with Task.Run, if I understand correctly and lets assume the task is not finished, the task runs on a different thread, while the invoking thread in which the Task.Run was invoked from is returned to the thread pool? How then will the original thread know that the other thread which handles the lambda finished and he can continue whatever code is after Task.Run?

Comment: @YonatanNir: `SynchronizationContext.Current` and `TaskScheduler.Current` are properties representing the current SyncCtx and task scheduler. `TaskScheduler.Default` is the thread pool task scheduler. Tasks don't run on different threads; truly asynchronous tasks [don't "run" on a thread at all](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). The original thread calls `Task.Run` and then continues executing; it doesn't wait for the lambda to complete.